# Rank a vector based on order and replace ties with their average

Tags: r, matlab, ranking

I'm new to R, and i find it quite interesting.

I have MATLAB code to rank a vector based on order which works fine.  Now I want to convert it to R code, a typical spearman ranking with ties:

```
# MATLAB CODE

function r=drank(x)

u = unique(x);
[xs,z1] = sort(x);
[z1,z2] = sort(z1);
r = (1:length(x))';
r=r(z2);

for i=1:length(u)

    s=find(u(i)==x);

    r(s,1) = mean(r(s));

end
```

This is what i tried:

```
# R CODE

x = c(10.5, 8.2, 11.3, 9.1, 13.0, 11.3, 8.2, 10.1)

drank <- function(x){

    u = unique(x)
    xs = order(x)
    r=r[xs]

    for(i in 1:length(u)){
        s=which(u[i]==x)
        r[i] = mean(r[s])  
    }

    return(r)
}
```

r <- drank(x)

Results:

```
r = 5, 1.5, 6.5, 3, 8, 6.5, 1.5, 4
```

`1.5` is average of `8.2` occurring twice ie. tie

`6.5` is average of `11.3` occurring twice

Can anyone help me check it?

Thanks,

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results.  Also, describe in words what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: @Andrie i have posted an example thank you.

Comment: You _should_ have done a search of SO before posting; This search strategy delivered 4 hits with the first Q answering your Q: `Rank order ties average  [r]`

Comment: Sure will do next time thanks

Answer (score 5):

R has a built-in function for ranking, called `rank()` and it gives precisely what you are looking for. `rank` has the argument `ties.method`, "a character string specifying how ties are treated", which defaults to `"average"`, i.e. replaces ties by their mean.

```
x = c(10.5, 8.2, 11.3, 9.1, 13.0, 11.3, 8.2, 10.1)
expected <- c(5, 1.5, 6.5, 3, 8, 6.5, 1.5, 4)

rank(x)
# [1] 5.0 1.5 6.5 3.0 8.0 6.5 1.5 4.0

identical(expected, rank(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Andrie thank you. can i see the function defination?

Comment: Yes.  Type `rank` into your console.  You can view the code for any function in this way.